# Test Progressive Web App installation with Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, progressive-web-apps

I am currently working on GUI tests for my Vue application using Selenium. I am writing the tests in C# and the tests seem to be running on a Google Chrome client.

The Vue application is a Progressive Web App (PWA) with a custom beforeinstallprompt event that adds some flair to the app installation. It does rely on pressing the 'Install' button on the native browser prompt to actually download the app and put it on the home screen, still.

Now I wanted to test this functionality in my GUI tests, but can't seem to figure out how... I know how to get to the browser's installation prompt but don't know how to interact with this.

See below the code I have working so far

```
var installPromptExistsInitially = IsElementVisible("#installPrompt"); // Check if the custom installPrompt exists before interacting with it

WaitForElement("#installPrompt"); // Always wait until the custom installPrompt is loaded

Click("#installApp"); // Click the install button on my custom prompt

// here I need to accept the browser's native installation prompt

var installPromptExistsAfterInstalling = IsElementVisible("#installPrompt"); // Check if the custom installPrompt has disappeared after actually installing the PWA

Assert.IsTrue(installPromptExistsInitially); // Assert that the prompt was there in the beginning
Assert.IsFalse(installPromptExistsAfterInstalling); // Assert that it is gone now
```

I hope that one of you can help me out on this one. Thanks in advance :)